# how to display message from logic.js file in hyperledger-composer

Tags: hyperledger-composer

i am using IBM online hyperledger composer playground at https://composer-playground.mybluemix.net

i have an if else condition, in the else part, i need to show an alert or an error message to the user if he has low balance.

i searched the internet and couldnt fine any source. below is one of the meaningful source which is talking about success component, but it doesnt show how to implement.

https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/894
and 
https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/539

how can we generate our own message to display to the end user?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for testing purposes in the Online Playground - you can do

1) use `alert()` eg working with Composer sample network and transactions here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/v0.16.x/packages/trade-network/lib/logic.js
           /**

```
 function tradeCommodity(trade) {

    alert("New Trade Commodity owner is " + trade.newOwner.firstName + ' ' + trade.newOwner.lastName);
```

to pop up a message. `alert()` is a standard JS function.

2) use `console.log()` (and hit SHIFT-CTRL-J to open the developer console)

```
    function tradeCommodity(trade) {

    console.log("New Trade Commodity owner is " + trade.newOwner.firstName + ' ' + trade.newOwner.lastName);
```